# Creating a Nested Custom QML Component `Component` in a C++ Class

Tags: c++, qt, qml

### The Problem

I am trying to create a QML Component (and by component, I mean a QML component of type `Component` that gets used by a `Loader`'s `sourceComponent` property) in a C++ class and pass it down to a QML File. I am using a `Loader` particularly to dynamically change a single area of the view based on user interaction with the UI elsewhere on that view. Here is how I am approaching the implementation:

`DynamicLoader.h`

```
class DynamicLoader: public QQuickItem {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QObject *mainComp READ getMainComp NOTIFY mainCompChanged)

public:
    DynamicLoader(QQuickItem *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

    QObject* getMainComp() const;

private:
    QObject* m_mainComp;

    QObject* createComponent();

signals:
    void mainCompChanged();

};
```

`DynamicLoader.cpp`

```
DynamicLoader::DynamicLoader(QQuickItem* parent)
    : QQuickItem(parent)
    , m_mainComp(new QObject(this)) {
    m_mainComp = createCustomComponent();
}

QObject *DynamicLoader::getMainComp() const {
    return m_mainComp;
}

QObject* DynamicLoader::createComponent() {
    QQmlEngine engine;

    QQmlComponent component(&engine,                     
    QUrl::fromLocalFile("://imports/components/CustomComponent.qml"));
    QObject* object = component.create();
    Q_ASSERT(object);

    QQuickItem* childItem = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(object);
    childItem->setParent(this);
    return childItem;
}
```

`CustomComponent.qml`

```
Component {
    CustomTextBox {
        text: "Custom Text"
    }
}
```

`CustomTextBox.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    property int containerWidth: 580
    property alias text: customText.text

    anchors.fill: parent

    Text {
        id: customText
        text: "Default Text"
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        width: parent.width
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        font.weight: Font.Bold
        font.pointSize: 100
        color: "white"
    }
}
```

**This, however, crashes the program with the following error message:**

**`QQmlComponent: Component is not ready`**, and fails at the `Q_ASSERT`.

### Other Findings

This same error occurs even when `CustomComponent.qml` is changed to simply `Component {}`. When I discovered this, I suspected that perhaps `QQmlComponent` already wraps the QML file with a `Component` type (please correct me if I am wrong), so I went ahead and converted the file to:

```
Item {
    CustomTextBox {
        text: "Custom Text"
    }
}
```

and got the same error.

Only when I change the file to the following does it not error out:

```
Item {
    Item {
    }
}
```

Lastly, the error does not occur when I implement `CustomComponent.qml` entirely in QML.

### Questions

1. Am I correct in thinking that declaring a QQmlComponent already wraps a QML file with the `Component` type? If not, how should I be creating a `Component` QML component in C++?
2. Why does the program crash when I create a nested custom component? Do I need to create the component through other means?

*Any help and corrections to fundamental misconceptions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.*

Comment: Probably you have some error in your costom component and so QML fails to create it.

Comment: @folibis that unfortunately is not true. I have confirmed that the nested custom component renders just fine when I implement it entirely through QML.

Comment: Ok, it would be great if you can provide code of both components so we could test it.

Comment: Btw, I've just looked at the question. Do you really wrap one component with another one? How do you thing the inner one should be instantiated?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've updated my entry to include the `CustomTextBox.qml` file, and modified the `CustomComponent.qml` accordingly. Can you also elaborate on what you mean by "wrapping one component with another one?" If you meant to ask if I need to, as of now, yet - because I am trying to dynamically set `sourceComponent` of QML's `Loader` component. As for your second question, do you mean how each newly generated Component through C++ should be instantiated? In the code I updated the entry with, I imagine a simple `setProperty` of `text` with metadata I have retrieved elsewhere.